# Que mi web se indexe y entren en https y no en http

Tags: html, .htaccess, https, redirección, dominio

Resulta que mi web ha sido indexada en google, pero cuando hacen click en cualquier página indexada entran en **http**://dominio.com en vez de de **https**://dominio.com

Cómo podría hacer de la forma más correcta posible y estandarizada que al entrar el usuario vaya a https ?

EDITO: resulta que de las webs que google ha indexado, el index es la única que no entra a https, el resto de páginas si entran https ¿ Cómo procedo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega esto a tu archivo .htaccess que está en la raiz de tu servidor, si no exite crea uno:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Con esto forzarás el uso de https en tu servidor.

Para redireccionar a dominio sin www.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.tudominio.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://tudominio.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Ya hice el htaccess pero si entro comiendo en la barra de direcciones wwww.dominio.com entra y no es htps, en cambio, si entro sin poner las www si entra en https, tengo que añadir algo más al htaccess para solucionar eso tambien ?

Comment: He agregado al código para forzar a que entren sin las www, aunque habría que ver porque el certificado SSL no te incluye el dominio con las www, puede ser un problema de configuración del certificado.

Comment: Esta ultima redireccion a sin www afecta en algo al posicionamiento y a lo que está indexado por google ?

Comment: Las urls indexadas serán redirigidas cuando un usuario entre a través de una búsqueda, con el tiempo google corregirá las urls, aunque yo recomiendo redireccionar a la inversa.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es forzar un redirect de http a https indicando que el cambio es permanente para que, eventualmente, los buscadores actualicen la página y la dejen como https.

La forma de lograr ese redirect dependerá del servidor donde esté montado tu sitio web.  Puedes buscar "redireccionar http to https linux" o "redireccionar http to https iis" en google para encontrar unas instrucciones de como hacerlo.